# infinite $m,n\neq0$ such as $m*n\neq0$

Tags: calculus

$x*y$ = $\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}$, where $x,y$ ∈ $R$

I only noticed that this law doesn't have neutral element.

I need to demonstrate that there are infinite pair numbers $(m,n)$ ( $m,n\neq 0$ ) such as $m*n\neq0$

How can I demonstrate this?

Comment: Notice that $\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}=0$ if and only if $x=y=0$

Comment: You need to use: "$\sqrt[3]{a}=0$ if and only if $a=0$" and "$b^2=0$ if and only if $b=0$".